# Need to make a DLC "packet" system for my iOS game

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, in-app-purchase, nsbundle

I'm developing a game for iOS and I need to make a system to download "packs" after the player bought them with In App Purchases.

I've search on the internet for a method like using a bundle, or just using web services, but I really don't know which one is the best.

Let me be specific:  in one pack the player has between 1-3 sprites, 1-2 music files, and 1-3 backgrounds.

So what I need to do is download that "pack" and store it as "purchased". What methods would be the most reusable and modular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest and most simple solution would be to bundle the DLC in to your app with an update and simply use an in app purchase to unlock them for the user. This saves their time and bandwidth as they no longer have to download the files and it saves you paying for a server to host it all.

Comment: This method looks like a good idea (The more easy the best) but there is one thing that i'm worry about. The game could become too voluminous. And does apple accept that method of buy/unlock ?

Comment: Releasing an "update" that contains the DLC will cause future downloaders of the app to download the updated app (which includes the DLC). This means that your application may be larger than the limit of 50 MB to download over the cellular network, ultimately decreasing your install base. Also, it bloats the applications size by providing content that most users will never even see. On the other hand, it makes things considerably easier...

Comment: @Yume117 Apple does indeed support this method of in app purchase. Obviously it increases the app size but if you're under 50MB with it then it's not much of a problem (compress those sprites, 8bit them if possible!)

Comment: Well if i can make a pack 1mo and guessing i've made only 10packs (just gessing) my application will be like 20mo+10mo... I've read somewhere that ios game should be less than 10mo. The size is a really big issue >.<

Comment: @Yume117 the iOS size limit for downloading over a cellular connection is currently 50MB, so if it's under that you're good to go! There's an excellent tutorial on unlockable in app purchases here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

Comment: Yep raywenderlich tutorials are really good i already passed there without going in details. Maybe i 'll go take a better look

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about this. In the past I created a system for a previous client that used a manifest that referenced all the files in the "pack", then downloaded each asset. The manifest could be updated to point to updated/different assets if needed, and contained a version number so that the system would know if it needed to update assets after the user had previously downloaded the pack. I probably wouldn't worry so much with a one-size-fits-all approach on this; just get something up and running for this one project that can be used on all DLC packs. Your next project will probably need heavy modifications for the same system to work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of a manifest, that's what i've done so far. i manage xml files local (gdataxml with a parser) and update those files with a WS. When a player successfully purchase a content, i retrieve the "pack content" by WS. To download store permanently and then use content should i use resource bundle ? Apple documentation isn't so clear about that >.<

Comment: Using a resource bundle may be easier, but might provide less flexibility. For example, if you needed to update a specific resource, but not the entire bundle (not sure if bundles are writable on iOS).

Comment: In Angry Bird-like game do you know what method they are using ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I can't imagine the level files are very large (probably just a few kilobytes), so I can't tell if it's actually downloading the content when purchases, or if it's prepackaged with the app.