# How create DLC system without AppStore updates but with iOS SDK payments

Tags: ios, app-store

According to this question: [Need to make a DLC “packet” system for my iOS game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433470/need-to-make-a-dlc-packet-system-for-my-ios-game). What if I want to download packet from my source but I still want to make payments by iOS SDK?

**Description**:I have an app and in that app I will have an update button. If someone clicks the button, the app will connect with my server and get a list of free and pay packages. In a package there will be 2-5 pictures, texts.

**My question** is, how should I solve the problem with payment and what that package should look like (zip or what?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I use [Objective-Zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/).